# Silverlight: bind DataGridTextColumn to external class property

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have a `DataGridTextColumn` which I bounded to a `Property` like this:

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Provider.Name, Mode= TwoWay}"/>
```

The problem is that when the cells in this column lose focus they are set to null. 
However when I bind my `DataGridTextColumn` directly to a name `Property`:

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode= TwoWay}"/>
```

It works just fine. My Provider class is as follows:

```
public class `Provider`
{
    [Display ( Name="ProviderLabel",ResourceType=typeof(LocalizedResources.LocalizedStrings))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know if the binding does happen or not since after I run the program with the first binding, the column header does contain the `ProviderLabel`.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type do you use for representing the row data? Does your row type offer a public propety with the name 'Provider' of type Provider? If not... then you can't expect the binding to find anything there.

Comment: Hm, seems like you are not very keen to get an answer on your question.